# Socket with two different Wi-Fi networks programming

Tags: sockets, ip

My model is
Server----> router1----->internet----> router2 ---->clients
Please help me out with this model programming using socket. Socket programming in python uses one IP for both server and client is running successfully.but I want server and client to run on different IP's.

Server is my laptop and clients are raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

The way that your internet works is that only your router is connected to the internet. The rest of your computers and raspberry pi's *are not connected to the internet* but the router does some tricks to make them think they are. This is called NAT (Network Address Translation). This is done to save IP addresses because there aren't enough IP addresses.

From the internet perspective your connection is just

```
router1----->internet----->router2
```

From the server perspective the connection is

```
server----->router1----->internet----->router2
```

From the client perspective the connection is

```
router1----->internet----->router2----->client
```

All computers think that the opposite router is the end of the connection.

The client must connect to router1's IP address and router1 must be configured so that it knows it will forward the connection to the server. This is called port forwarding.

The server program doesn't need any changes.